# Your app is not compatible for Tablet?

Tags: android, compatibility, tablet

I have developed an app, and it works fine on handsets yet, on the developer console it says

> Your app is not compatible with the tablets.

I have also designed and set support for for *large* and *xlarge* screens as true. And I do not use any of the screen compatibility fields either. Also, I have set the *required attributes* to *false* for telephony and location features in my *Manifest* like below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
```

Could someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832664/app-not-compatible-with-tablet

Comment: and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733070/why-is-app-not-compatible-with-tablets-after-update